# wordpress onpage load auto download zip file

Tags: php, wordpress, customization, download

I am try to implement php script for zip file downloading. It work fine when I  write below code before get_header(); in wordpress file but page is not open
and when I write code after get_header(); then the page will open but it print the zip file on page. HOW TO FIX THIS ISSUE.

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($filename));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filepath.$filename));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($filepath.$filename);
exit;
```

Comment: This is likely happening because you aren't supposed to output anything after output goes to browser, so do as you are saying, keep it before the `get_header()`. Is there some reason why you don't want this?

Comment: I also want to open the page after download zip file if I put the code before get_header() then the only file is download and page is not opening. http://islamforall.tv/gt_dev_project/wp/download/

Comment: You're doing this in the wrong place.  You need to use the `init` action hook, and write a function.  Further, you need it to be conditional (I assume) somehow, otherwise isn't this going to download every time you load the page?

Comment: I used action hook and write function for this but it not work.

Comment: If you want to go to a new page after download, you may want to build a JavaScript that takes you to the new page after the download starts